# Refcursors in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Good Morning,

I have a quick question on how to see the data that is fetched in an Output refcursor

I'm executing the below block, its successfully executed but I want to see the data fetched in Output RefCursor, by the way I'm using PGADMIN 4 tool to connect to Postgres Servers,

```
BEGIN;
SELECT prod_package_list ('G6028|G6026|G6025|G6024|G6022|G6021|G6020', NULL);
FETCH ALL IN vref_cur; 
COMMIT;
```

I found online and according to them I should follow the below format,

```
BEGIN;
SELECT test_prod_package_list ('G6028|G6026|G6025|G6024|G6022|G6021|G6020', NULL, 'vref_cur');
FETCH ALL IN "vref_cur"; 
COMMIT;
```

But the above execution block throws an error 
function prod_package_list(unknown, unknown, unknown) does not exist,

The function is as follows,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.prod_package_list(
    prodlist text,
    billcodelist text,
    OUT vref_cur refcursor)
    RETURNS refcursor
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
AS $BODY$

BEGIN
    vref_cur := 'vref_cur';

    IF prodlist IS NOT NULL THEN
        OPEN vref_cur FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT
            b.package_id, a.product_id, a.pdct_ctlg_id, a.product_name, a.billing_system, a.billing_code, a.fulfill_system, a.fulfill_code, a.speed_code, a.product_type, a.product_type_value, a.return_auth_applies, a.return_auth_term, a.nrc_waiver, a.nrc_waiver_product_id, a.linked_nrc_product_id, a.national_east_west, a.lata_list, a.state_list, a.product_info_url, a.isp_prov_flags, a.product_coefficient, a.last_updated, a.product_keywords, a.combo_product_list, a.additional_info, a.usoc_info, a.min_billing_days, a.data_nrf_product_id, a.video_nrf_product_id, a.account_line_level, a.web_desc, a.orderguicd, a.prod_startdate, a.prod_enddate, b.pdct_ctlg_id, b.package_name, b.billing_code, b.category_id, b.standalone_cpe, b.standalone_truckroll, b.btn_billed, b.emp_discount, b.package_type, b.last_updated, b.pkg_detail_descr, b.grandfathered AS pkg_grandfathered,
            CASE CONCAT_WS('', a.grandfathered, c.pkg_prod_grandfathered)
                WHEN 'YY' THEN 'Y'
                WHEN 'YN' THEN 'Y'
                WHEN 'NY' THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
            END AS grandfathered
            FROM ssp2_pcat.products AS a, ssp2_pcat.packages AS b, ssp2_pcat.package_products AS c
            WHERE strpos(prodlist, CONCAT_WS('', '|', a.product_id, '|')) > 0 
            AND a.product_id = c.product_id AND c.package_id = b.package_id 
            AND c.start_date <= LOCALTIMESTAMP AND c.end_date >= LOCALTIMESTAMP
            ORDER BY 1;

    ELSIF billcodelist IS NOT NULL THEN
        OPEN vref_cur FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT
            b.package_id, a.product_id, a.pdct_ctlg_id, a.product_name, a.billing_system, a.billing_code, a.fulfill_system, a.fulfill_code, a.speed_code, a.product_type, a.product_type_value, a.return_auth_applies, a.return_auth_term, a.nrc_waiver, a.nrc_waiver_product_id, a.linked_nrc_product_id, a.national_east_west, a.lata_list, a.state_list, a.product_info_url, a.isp_prov_flags, a.product_coefficient, a.last_updated, a.product_keywords, a.combo_product_list, a.additional_info, a.usoc_info, a.min_billing_days, a.data_nrf_product_id, a.video_nrf_product_id, a.account_line_level, a.web_desc, a.orderguicd, a.prod_startdate, a.prod_enddate, b.pdct_ctlg_id, b.package_name, b.billing_code, b.category_id, b.standalone_cpe, b.standalone_truckroll, b.btn_billed, b.emp_discount, b.package_type, b.last_updated, b.pkg_detail_descr, b.grandfathered AS pkg_grandfathered,
            CASE CONCAT_WS('', a.grandfathered, c.pkg_prod_grandfathered)
                WHEN 'YY' THEN 'Y'
                WHEN 'YN' THEN 'Y'
                WHEN 'NY' THEN 'Y'
                ELSE 'N'
            END AS grandfathered
            FROM ssp2_pcat.products AS a, ssp2_pcat.packages AS b, ssp2_pcat.package_products AS c
            WHERE strpos(billcodelist, CONCAT_WS('', '|', a.billing_code, '|')) > 0 
            AND a.product_id = c.product_id AND c.package_id = b.package_id 
            AND c.start_date <= LOCALTIMESTAMP AND c.end_date >= LOCALTIMESTAMP
            ORDER BY 1;

    ELSE
        RAISE USING hint = -20001, message = 'Product List and Billing Code Lists are empty.', detail = 'User-defined exception';
    END IF;

END;

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION ssp2_pcat.prod_package_list(text, text)
    OWNER TO ssp2_pcat;
```

Please advise,

Comment: It's hard to advise you anything because your function body is a secret.

Comment: Updated with Function Body!

Comment: Why use a refcursor at all? You could simply declare the function as `returns table (...)`, then you can use `select * from prod_package_list(...)`

Comment: Unrelated, but: `WHERE strpos(billcodelist, CONCAT_WS('', '|', a.billing_code, '|'))` can be simplified to `WHERE a.billing_code = any(string_to_arry(billcodelist, '|'))` or even better: pass `billcodelist` as an array, not a delimited string.

Comment: Thank You Sirr, 
Always your response is very helpful to learn new stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN` parameter to pass a cursor name. Do not forget to `RETURN vref_cursor`. Working example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(arg1 text, arg2 text, vref_cursor refcursor) 
RETURNS refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN vref_cursor FOR SELECT generate_series(1,3);
    RETURN vref_cursor;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

BEGIN;
SELECT my_func('first arg', 'second arg', 'vref_cursor');
FETCH ALL IN vref_cursor;
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time for looking into this Klin, made those changes and the below script is executing fine.

    `BEGIN;
    SELECT prod_package_list_test('G6028|G6026|G6025|G6024|G6022|G6021|G6020', 'vref_cur');
    FETCH ALL IN vref_cur;
    COMMIT; `

But how do I see the result set when I ran the above script.

Comment: Execute the statements one by one in psql, you will see the results after `FETCH`.

Comment: Just for my understanding, so don't we have any way to see the results by executing the script using the tool PGADMIN4, instead of PSQL?

Comment: You can also do this in PgAdmin, executing the commands one by one. If you run the whole script at once, you cannot see the results as the last command is `COMMIT`.

Comment: You are so Awesome Klin, it worked good as mentioned above!
All these days I'm executing the whole block at one time instead of one statement at a time :)